Unsupported Server Component type: {...} / next js 14
My project is work manager in next js 14. I used userProvider and it gives error like "Error: Unsupported Server Component type: {...}" How can I solve. below I provide my code.
This is my code:
Layout.js
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";
import UserProvider from "@/context/userProvider";
import NavBar from "@/components/NavBar";
const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
    return (
        <html lang="en">
            <body className={inter.className}>
                <UserProvider >
                    <NavBar/>
                    {children}
                </UserProvider> 
            </body>
        </html>
    );
}

userProvider.js
"use client";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import UserContext from "./userContext";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import { currentUser } from "@/services/userService";

const UserProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(undefined);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function load() {
            try {
                const tempUser = await currentUser();
                console.log(tempUser);
                setUser({ ...tempUser });
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
                // toast.error("error in loading current  user");
                setUser(undefined);
            }
        }

        load();
    }, []);

    return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
            {children}
        </UserContext.Provider>
    );
};

export default UserProvider;`


Wrap the provider around your <body />
